# Emulate horizontal scrolling with Shift key

Tags: xorg, mouse

I want to emulate horizontal scrolling when I use my (vertical) scroll wheel and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

In some applications (Chrom{e,ium}) this already works, but I'm looking for a generic solution for X applications.

The closest I got so far is `xbindkeys` + `xdotool`.

```
# ~/.xbindkeysrc
"xdotool click 6"
  shift + b:4

"xdotool click 7"
  shift + b:5
```

The Problem is that `xbindkeys` seems to miss some events, and occasionally a vertical scroll "gets through". This is very annoying. It looks like `xbindkeys` is using some kind of polling?

Also I don't like spawning hundreds of shell commands per seconds.

I got a small screen and have to scroll horizontally a lot.

How can I achieve generic horizontal scrolling?

**UPDATE:**

There is another way that does mostly what I want with `xbindkeys` and `xmodmap`.

```
"xmodmap -e 'pointer = 1 2 3 6 7 4 5 8 9 10'"
  c:50
"xmodmap -e 'pointer = default'"
  release + shift + c:50
```

When <kbd>Shift</kbd> is held, the pointer buttons 4 and 5 are mapped to 6 and 7. (Buttons 4/5 are fore vertical scrolling and 6/7 for horizontal scrolling). `c:50` is the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. On key release the default pointer mapping is restored.

This solves the "too many events" Problem nicely. However, the Shift key doesn't work as normal modifier anymore. I tried to re-issue the <kbd>Shift</kbd> press/release events with `xdotool` like this:

```
"xmodmap -e 'pointer = 1 2 3 6 7 4 5 8 9 10';  xdotool keydown Shift_L"
  c:50
"xmodmap -e 'pointer = default';  xdotool keyup Shift_L"
  release + shift + c:50
```

According to `xev` the <kbd>Shift</kbd> events get through, but I think it's not recognized as a modifier any more. For example, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> wouldn't produce an uppercase `A`.

Comment: You can also do horizontal scrolling with Ctrl+Arrows for many programs.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me in Firefox. I'm looking for a "generic" Solution that works everywhere.

Comment: Would it be a problem to run something as root, e.g. using sudo?

Comment: It's not optimal to have to sudo. I assume you mean sudo-ing everytime Shift is pressed?
Could you elaborate what you have in mind?

Comment: This might be pointless, but once upon a time [this](http://pastebin.com/trDWZjsR) worked for me in `~/.xbindkeysrc.scm`. At some point it failed, but it might work on your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an acceptable solution for me.

I didn't find a way to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> or any other key as my modifier to rotate the wheel axis as long as it is pressed.

I'm now using a simple `.xbindkeysrc` with a toggle button:

```
"~/toggle.sh"
  alt + x
```

The toggle.sh script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
on()
{
  xmodmap -e 'pointer = 1 2 3 6 7 4 5 8 9 10'
}

off()
{
  xmodmap -e 'pointer = default'
}

if xmodmap -pp | grep -q '4.*6'; then
  off
else
  on
fi
```

This allows me to toggle the behaviour. When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, my mouse wheel axis is rotated, and when I press it again, it's set to the default.

That should work for now.

If someone finds a way to do it with <kbd>Shift</kbd> as a "modifier" (mouse axis rotate as long as it's pressed), please let me know.

EDIT: As <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> is a commonly used hotkey, I changed it to:

```
(xbindkey '(control "b:3") "toggle-wheel.sh")
```

(I switched to guile configuration so the above should be in a file named `.xbindkeysrc.scm`)

This will toggle the scroll wheel direction with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + right mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [btnx](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/btnx/) and it's [gui config tool](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/btnx-config/).

More recent [Ubuntu package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/btnx/0.4.11-3ubuntu2) and [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/btnx-config/0.4.9-4ubuntu1)

After you do the button detection on your mouse using btnx-config just map "Scroll Up" along with a shift button modifier to whatever x button pressing you would like.

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a problem getting it to build on fedora though.

Comment: I found a rpm package for btnx now. I don't find a way to map a modifier as a source event (i.e. Shift+WheelUp). I only can map from WheelUp *to* Shift+some other key. Am I missing something?

I also tried to "detect" Shift+WheelUp in the first place, but it said "Button already mapped". The rawcode was 0x02010008 for both cases (Shift pressed and not pressed). I don't think btnx can handle multiple input devices at all (Mouse+Keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

As hinted [here](https://superuser.com/a/27254/125959), I installed [imwheel](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/imwheel/), then created `~/.imwheelrc` with the following content.

```
".*"
Shift_L, Up, Left
Shift_L, Down, Right
```

I then ran `imwheel -b 45` in the terminal. I tested, and I haven't noticed the diagonal problems associated with high scrolling and xbindkeys.

N.B. `-b 45` restricts `imwheel` to capture only up and down scrolling, preventing it from blocking (e.g.) `xbindkeys` bindings for thumb buttons.

### Problems

However, there are several problems associated with this.

- It's inconsistent. I could get it to work with Firefox and Gwenview out of the box, but Inkscape and GIMP didn't work. I could use window matching to not match Inkscape/GIMP, but there should be some way to have it work universally.
- Even worse, it prevents some other default events, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll wheel</kbd>, which is normally used to zoom. I tried putting things like `Control_L, Up, Control_L|Up` in `~/.imwheelrc`, but this didn't work.
- `imwheel` sends horizontal scroll wheel events to the active window, not the window under the mouse cursor. This is counter to the default behaviour of the scroll wheel. This also suggests that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> workaround in the point above would also be sub-optimal.
- `imwheel` appears to be no longer in development. It's been stuck on the pre-release version for the last 10 years (since 2004).