# Keyboard shortcut for horizontal scrolling

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, window, scrolling

Is there a utility I could use to scroll the active window horizontally using the keyboard?

Comment: I am not sure if this is a duplicate of this question. However, it is worth looking into. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111386/emulate-horizontal-scrolling-with-shift-key

Comment: @Ramesh The op there wants to alter the behavior of the scroll wheel on his mouse.  I don't want to use the mouse at all, just the keyboard.

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 2):

Install `xbindkeys` and `xautomation`. Edit `~/.xbindkeysrc.scm` and write:

```
; bind (Windows key + arrows) to horizontal scroll events
(xbindkey '(mod4 Left)  "xte 'mouseclick 6'")
(xbindkey '(mod4 Right) "xte 'mouseclick 7'")
```

Run `xbindkeys`

If you want to use a different set of keys, use `xbindkeys --multikey` to find out the codes.

**References:**

- This is a slight modification of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/404830/702503), adapted to your (and mine!) use case.
- Same content, but [more detailed](https://askubuntu.com/a/407233/702503).

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.  For some reason `xte 'mouseclick 6'` and `xte 'mouseclick 7'` don't work for me.  This did the trick: `xte 'keydown Shift_L' 'mouseclick 4' 'keyup Shift_L'`.  It's not a complete solution, though, because it only works if the mouse is *over* the window in question.

Comment: @AryehLeibTaurog So... will you accept my answer?