# How can I make imwheel leave most modifier actions as default?

Tags: mouse, scrolling

I'm [attempting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151195/18887) to horizontal scroll with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>scroll wheel</kbd>. I've tried using `imwheel`, using the following in `~/.imwheelrc`

```
".*"
Shift_L, Up, Left
Shift_L, Down, Right
```

I then run `imwheel -b 45`. This makes <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>scroll wheel</kbd> work as expected.

However, it prevents some other default events, like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>scroll wheel</kbd> and <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>scroll wheel</kbd> from being passed. Instead, these appear to be interpreted as a normal (unmodified) scroll.

I tried putting things like `Control_L, Up, Control_L|Up` in `~/.imwheelrc`, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5
```

in your .imwheelrc should do the trick. Be sure to restart imwheel for the changes to take effect. Note that starting imwheel multiple times leads to undefined behavior.

### EDIT

As per feedback from the OP, the key is to map to `Button4`/`Button5` instead of `Up`/`Down`. Hence the following worked in `~/.imwheelrc`, followed by running `imwheel -b 45`. (For the sake of completeness I also accounted for <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Hyper</kbd>, <kbd>Meta</kbd> and the right-hand-side keys.)

```
".*"
Shift_L, Up, Left
Shift_L, Down, Right
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Super_L, Up, Super_L|Button4
Super_L, Down, Super_L|Button5
Alt_L, Up, Alt_L|Button4
Alt_L, Down, Alt_L|Button5
Hyper_L, Up, Hyper_L|Button4
Hyper_L, Down, Hyper_L|Button5
Meta_L, Up, Meta_L|Button4
Meta_L, Down, Meta_L|Button5
Shift_R, Up, Left
Shift_R, Down, Right
Control_R, Up,   Control_R|Button4
Control_R, Down, Control_R|Button5
Super_R, Up, Super_R|Button4
Super_R, Down, Super_R|Button5
Alt_R, Up, Alt_R|Button4
Alt_R, Down, Alt_R|Button5
Hyper_R, Up, Hyper_R|Button4
Hyper_R, Down, Hyper_R|Button5
Meta_R, Up, Meta_R|Button4
Meta_R, Down, Meta_R|Button5
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work, and in fact is worse than before. Specifically, both `Ctrl`+scroll-wheel and `Shift`+scroll-wheel appear to send vanilla scroll-wheel events. However, I took some inspiration from your answer, and mapped to `Button4`/`Button5` instead of `Up`/`Down`, which worked. I'll add an edit to your answer and accept it.