# How can I prevent imwheel from allowing some scrolling events to "pass-through"?

Tags: xorg, mouse, scrolling

After [much](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151195/18887) [troubleshooting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279732/18887), I finally found a way to map <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse-wheel</kbd> to horizontal scroll, using `imwheel`. The pertinent part in `~/.imwheelrc` is as follows.

```
".*"
Shift_L, Up, Button6, 10
Shift_L, Down, Button7, 10
```

This maps <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse-wheel</kbd> to horizontal scroll, and also makes it scroll more rapidly. (I've also tried removing the `, 10`, with the same issues.) When I hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and scroll, some of the events "pass-through", and occasionally it scrolls up or down as well, resulting in a diagonal scroll.

In comparison, when I have the following in `~/.imwheelrc`, there are no scroll events that "pass-through".

```
".*"
Shift_L, Up, Left
Shift_L, Down, Right
```

However, this maps the <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> keystrokes to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse-wheel</kbd>, which will scroll horizontally in some specific cases, but isn't correct for most situations.

How can I prevent `imwheel` from allowing some scrolling events to "pass-through"?